# Reload a PDF in Chromium while keeping the page

Tags: pdf, chromium, reload

Say I'm reading a long PDF on the built-in PDF viewer in Chromium, and I'm currently at page 100/200. If I reload the PDF, I end up on the first page. Is it possible to reload a PDF and stay on the same page number than the one I was looking at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I figured it out: just append `#page=100` (or whatever page number you want to stay on) to the URL of the PDF and it works.